Why can "the politics of repression" creep into commercial law as well?

"Some people think that you can divide or separate commercial cases as a phenomenon from political or human rights cases, but I think that's kind of a perilous path, because what happens is the politics of repression creeps into the commercial area as well," Michael Davis, an international law professor and global fellow at the U.S.-backed Wilson Center think tank said.

I am one of these people who think this. Why can't you "divide or separate commercial cases as a phenomenon from political or human rights cases"?
Please flesh out how "the politics of repression creeps into the commercial area as well" ?

Ever heard of Masterpiece Cake or 303?

Segregation and Jim Crow laws?

@littleadv oh, and Brown I?

from the article, "Davis said any perceived diminution of legal protections affects the confidence of commercial entities over the enforcement of contracts."

The fact that Masterpiece, etc., involved commercial transactions doesn't make them    "commercial cases," at least not in the sense that phrase is used here. We're talking more about cases surrounding contract and property law.

@bdb484 Maybe redlining is a better example? Or food deserts.

@Trish never heard them when I posted. I just looked up Masterpiece Cakeshop v. Colorado Civil Rights Commission, 584 U.S. 617 (2018). 303 Creative LLC v. Elenis, 600 U.S. 570 (2023). But how are these constitutional law cases relevant to commercial law, or my questions?

@littleadv I didn't know Jim Crow laws. I just looked it up. but how are Jim Crow laws relevant to commercial litigation, or my question?

@Barmar how are redlining or food deserts  relevant to commercial litigation, or my question?

@user1110341 You are correct that none of these are commercial law cases. They are just civil-rights cases that arise out of commercial transactions.

Imagine you’re suing the Hong Kong government over a contract dispute
If Hong Kong judges have learned, through decisions made on political and human rights cases, that their careers and liberty depends on them deciding the way the Hong Kong government wants, what do you think your chances are?

doesn't your question apply to main land China, and Western business in China? American, European corporations know that mainland Chinese judges  decide the way the CCP want. But American, European corporations still do business in  China!

@user1110341 yes, and they charge a judicial risk premium for doing so. HK has so far avoided such a cost, but the risk is that if the judiciary is understood not to be independent, foreign corporations will increase their prices to cover that risk.

I never knew that "they charge a judicial risk premium for doing so"! Please elaborate on this  "judicial risk premium"? Has any news or lawyers reported  on this?
